# I have an issue importing. CSV file to pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, csv-import

I am not able to import the CSV file to pgAdmin. An error called 'Utility not found' appears and told me to correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog when I click the Import/Export Data Button.
I am using PostgreSQL 15 and Windows 11 is my OS.

I went to the preference dialog and imputed "C:\Program Files\PosgresSQL\15\bin" in the binary path so that I will be able import the CSV file but error message " 'C:\Program Files\PosgresSQL\15\bin\psql.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog"

How can I address the issue?

Comment: _"PosgresSQL"_: the missing "**t**" is a typo perhaps?

Comment: I have included it but it didn't work too.